# How to set `forwardRef: true` globally in React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to set `forwardRef: true` globally when using React Redux `connect` function.

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {}, null, { 
    forwardRef: true
})(promptDialogComponent);
```